# Change font size for pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I would simply like to change the font size of a pivot table produced with a macro.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
   .PivotFields("FieldName").ShowDetail = False
   .DataBodyRange.Font.Size = 10
End With
```

I am using this right now to change the font size, but this only effects the cells that contain data, and leaves out the cells that are field names. I would like to change the font size of everything in the pivot table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
   .PivotFields("FieldName").ShowDetail = False
   .TableRange1.Font.Size = 10
End With
```

Comment: I found this to be very useful. Referencing ranges of a pivot table. [URL](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)